# High speed communications on a lower speed controler

Tags: microcontroller, communication

I am new to electronics, I'm trying to get my head around this concept.

As I understand it, on any processor, you will be able to switch an output on or off, at a rate no faster than the speed of that processor.  So a 8Mhz chip could (ideally) switch an input on or off at a rate of 8 million times a second.

HDMI 2.0 specification calls for a transmission rate of up to 18 Gbit/s.  How is this possible without an 18Gzh processor?

Comment: HDMI uses three connections in parallel to transfer that data. Therefore, the maximum data-rate per wire (differential pair, actually) is 6 Gbit/s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such fast outputs are never handled directly by a processor. That would be called "bit banging" and is really only practical for bit rates that are a small fraction of the CPU instruction cycle rate (note that a chip with an 8MHz external clock might internally run at 2MHz or 200MHz instruction rate).

Instead there are peripherals that are dedicated arrangements of gates, flip-flops and registers that are used to serialize data, perhaps directly from memory (DMA = direct memory access). There may be an internal memory bus dedicated just to getting data out of a frame buffer at that rate. In the case of HDMI there would likely be a dedicated graphic processor (GPU) optimized for video processing.

In the case of the Broadcom BCM2835 SOC used in the Raspberry PI, the GPU is a VideoCore 4 ARM1176. It would be nice to see the internals of such a chip, but Broadcom holds the cards close to the chest, and an NDA and a substantiated intent to use a substantial volume of chips is the price of entry.

Comment: Ok, using DMA, would the theatrical maximum transfer rate be the instruction frequency times the largest register in bits (say 32)?  It looks like DMA is mostly connected to a level1 or level2 cache and not to the registers directly, so maybe the maximum rate would really be the register size times the level 1 cache speed.  If this is the case, even the raspberry Pi at 700mhz should be able to pull off 16gb/s.  So the short answer is, "by transmitting in parallel".

Comment: This still doesn't quite answer my question though.  I think now I have a better idea what I'm trying to say.  "In order to transmit at given rate, is it fair to say there are transistors switching at that rate?"  So with the 6Gb/s HDMI rate (thanks Connor wolf), there are transistors that are switching at 6 billion times a second.  And using gates it re-parallels the signal and there by slowing it down to a processor manageable rate.  Is that correct?